# Linker can only find part of .o in .a file

Tags: c++, c, mingw, static-libraries, mingw32

I am trying to use mingw-w64 to create a static lib on windows.
[Catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GKvt.png)
Static Lib src:

```
// test.h
#ifndef __TEST_H
#define __TEST_H

int add(int a, int b);
int div(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);

#endif

// add.c
#include"test.h"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

// sub.c
#include"test.h"

int sub(int a, int b)
{
   return a - b;
}

// div.c
#include"test.h"

int div(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

I use these command to create static lib:

```
PS D:\ThisPC\Desktop\dlltest> gcc -c *.c
PS D:\ThisPC\Desktop\dlltest> ar rcs libtest.a *.o
```

Src of app which use this lib:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"test.h"

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    printf("Input two bumbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    printf("%d / %d = %d\n", m, n, div(m, n));
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", m, n, add(m, n));
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n", m, n, sub(m, n));

    return 0;
}
```

Everything is OK.But when I use the lib, I get link error.

```
PS D:\ThisPC\Desktop\dlltest\app> gcc -I./include -L./lib -ltest -o app main.c  
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cc04bSGs.o:main.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `add'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\cc04bSGs.o:main.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `sub'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I delete printf(add()) and printf(sub()) ,it can work.
Linker can only find div label in .a file.

Comment: Are you sure that your command for "ar" builds the library in the subdirectory "lib"? Did you check the contents of the library?

Comment: As @thebusybee hints, the first step here would probably be something like `ar t libtest.a` to see whether the library actually contains all three object files.

Comment: thanks~ I try it just now, but it contains all obj files indeed.@thebusybee @JerryCoffin

Comment: `#define __TEST_H` That name is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should use another header guard.

Comment: @eerorika thanks. I have changed it, but it still don't work.

Comment: On the face of it, `-L./lib` does nothing but maybe `-L.` might help.  Also note that `div()` is a standard C library function declared in `<stdlib.h>`.  That name is probably being linked from the standard C library.

Comment: According to the posted commands, `libtest.a` was created in `D:\ThisPC\Desktop\dlltest`, but you're telling gcc to look for it in `D:\ThisPC\Desktop\dlltest\app\lib`.

Comment: I have copied it over.

Comment: In Windows the link order is important. Try putting `-ltest` after `-o app main.c`.